# JQuery select2 external content cannot select

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery select2 and trying to find external content.

I have enabled tags and added multiple to the HTML element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#selUser").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "/section/tickets?action=get_contacts",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    searchTerm: params.term // search term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (response) {
                return {
                    results: response
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        tags: true,
    });
});
</script>

<select id='selUser' style='width: 200px;' multiple="multiple">
 <option value='0'>- Search user -</option>
</select>
```

this is showing results from the Ajax call and searching fine, but the options returned in the ajax call i am unable to select.

The value searched for can be clicked and will dynamically create a new option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may require this answer in future, you can use this JQuery:

```
$(".select2, .select2-multiple").on('select2:open', function (e) {
    $('.select2-search input').prop('focus',false);
})
```

This will pickup all elements with a class of `.select2` or `.select2-multiple` which is what Select2 automatically gives elements and then the focus on the input box will be removed.